# Firebase Functions - https onRequest "HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors"

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm having some major issues with my firebase functions. I'm trying to create an `https` request so that I can send data to Firebase.

I have a super simple code just to test, and it's causing errors:

Here is my code (there should be no problem with this code):

```
exports.fetchPosts = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
    res.send("Hello!")
})
```

my `index.ts` file is 700 lines long.. without `fetchPosts` it deploys perfectly fine.. with `fetchPosts` I get these errors..

Here is the error:

> !  functions: failed to create function fetchPosts
>
> HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors

and here is the verbose error message:

> [2019-06-22T16:09:13.362Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 400 vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, date=Sat, 22 Jun 2019 16:09:11 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=0, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39", accept-ranges=none, connection=close
> [2019-06-22T16:09:13.362Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY code=400, message=The request has errors, status=INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=[@type=type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest, fieldViolations=[field=runtime, description=Runtime field cannot be empty.]]
> !  functions: failed to create function fetchPosts
> HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors

Any ideas what the issue might be? This seems ridiculous, as the code literally *should* work.

Comment: The error is saying there's a problem with the request.  How *exactly* are you making the request?

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm not sure I understand what you mean by how I'm making the request... It's a function in my Functions file and I'm trying to deploy it via: `firebase deploy --only functions`, but it's producing that error. If I remove the `fetchPosts` function from the code it deploys perfectly fine

Comment: If you're having problems with deployment that don't have actionable messages you can follow, you should contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: The error message is telling you that you have not specified the runtime. What is your deploy command?

Comment: @JohnHanley I deploy with `firebase deploy --only functions`..

Comment: You have no other files that are part of your deployment. You are leaving something out which is the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this issue after weeks!! What finally worked for me:

- `npm i -g firebase-tools@latest`
- Deleted `package-lock.json` file
- Deleted `node_modules` folder
- `npm install`
- `firebase deploy`

Hope that can help someone in the same position!!