# Firebase function not executing for some requests

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.notificaion = functions
.region("asia-south1")
.runWith({
  timeoutSeconds: 12,
})
.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Notification from sp");
});
```

The above cloud function is working with most of the requests. But it is not working with this particular request. It is not even getting executed. I've searched for the function execution in logs. There is no log for that request. This function is used to receive notifications from an external service.

This is the external service's log. It is getting 200 response.
[image]

I've changed the notification URL to a webhook to test the external service. This is the request I've received.
[image]

What can be the reason it is not executing the above request?

Comment: What particular service are you using it with?

Comment: Use `res.send('Response message')` after `console.log` to end `HTTP` functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Cloud Functions `https.onRequest` method, you can set it's response body and code.

```js
res.status(200).send("Notification from sp");
```

You can read about some additional methods for ending a HTTP point [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions)

Comment: The problem is, the function is not even triggering the event. Its working for all the other requests except the one I've attached above.

Comment: something else could be going wrong, the function is possibly hanging, invalid request, cold starts before the timeout, etc.
it could also be programmatic issues with your project and a clean install and updated is needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56818978/2301161  
Further debugging is required.